# Как выбрать последнюю часть ссылки через PHP?

Tags: php

Как сделать, чтобы данный PHP-код выводил только последнюю часть текущей ссылки страницы?
Например, ссылка текущей страницы `site.ru/alias/path/cut-me`
Необходимо, чтобы выводилось только `cut-me`

```
<?php 
  $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $url = explode('?', $url);
  $url = $url[0]; 
  echo $url; 
?>
```

Comment: После выполнения данного кода ищите в строке $url слэш. И обрезайте строку по нему.

Comment: @nightflash но ведь количество слэшей может быть каким угодно. Как взять именно последний?

Comment: Ищите слэш с конца. Например, обратным циклом.

Comment: @nightflash пока что только изучаю PHP, буду благодарен, если Вы продемонстрируете правильный способ как сделать это

Comment: Даже проще: есть функция strripos, которая ищет последнее вхождение подстроки.

Comment: наверное, можно *снова* использовать ту же функцию, которая использовалась для отдления "?"?

Comment: но *ещё проще* написать заголовок своего вопроса в адресной строке браузера и нажать Ентер

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение. Добавлен поиск слэша и выделение подстроки по найденной позиции слэша.

```
<?php 
  $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $url = explode('?', $url);
  $url = $url[0]; 
  $pos = strripos($url, '/');
  $s = substr($url, $pos + 1);
  echo $s; 
?>
```